# Creating a JS keypad, function undefined?

Tags: javascript

I had this keypad working but I'm not sure why now it says that the functions are undefined when you click one of the buttons. It's an odd issue and my brain is mush looking at it and trying different things for an hour. Appreciate any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/S47e9/1/

```
function number_write(x) {
var text_box = document.getElementById("numbText");
if (x >= 0 && x <= 9) {
    if (isNaN(text_box.value)) text_box.value = NULL;
    text_box.value = (text_box.value * 10) + x;
}
console.log(x);
}

function number_clear() {
document.getElementById("numbText").value = "";
}
```

Comment: check out http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/  find the "Num pad"  you might find it useful!

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to use the little bit of code that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are loading before the page, causing the handlers to not know about the functions. In the fiddle, on the left hand side, change the 2nd dropdown from `OnLoad` to `no wrap <in head>` -- http://jsfiddle.net/S47e9/2/

Comment: Thank you, I can see that working. How can I do the same on my page? I have the JS at the bottom of the page after everything has loaded. Should it be moved into the <head> section?

Comment: It should be working just fine at the bottom, what errors do you see in the console/

Comment: I don't see any errors. I'm using it in conjunction with jQuery UI for a project that is 5 pages: 1 landing and 4 sub-pages. I have the number pad on Page3. I don't get errors but the value the input field's value is not set. If I go back to the landing then back to Page3, it works. I believe that the code is not being loaded properly until I load it twice.

Comment: I figured out what's causing the issue, don't know of an actual fix but jQuery is prefetching the pages. If I go to Page2 before it's prefetched, the code isn't don't loading. If I give it a second, it works. Thanks for the help.